# SortBy da dataTable do primefaces não funciona

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Bom dia, pessoal.
Sou novo aqui no fórum e gostaria ter a ajuda de vocês para a seguinte situação.
O sortBy da minha datatable não está funcionando corretamente. A dataTable simplesmente perde o seu formato de tabela e apresenta o conteúdo inline.
Em algumas páginas ela aparece normal, mas em outras ela perde a configuração.

Estou utilizando o primefaces 5.3.
Agradeço toda colaboração

xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/template/modelo/modeloCidadao.xhtml">

```
<ui:define name="conteudo" >       
    <h:form id="formGeral">
        <p:panel id="parlamentares" header="Parlamentares" class="panel-height-front panel-border-color">
            <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" class="ui-fluid">
                <p:panelGrid id="panelPeriodo" columns="1" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-12" class="panelgrid-noborder">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Período de Legislatura"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.periodoSelecionado}" class="panelgrid-item-width-min20max40">  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{per.periodoNome}" itemValue="#{per.periodoNome}" value="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.periodos}" var="per"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.consultarParlamentarPorPeriodo()}" update="dtParlamentares"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:dataTable id="dtParlamentares" value="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.membros}" var="parlamentar"  rowStyleClass="#{cont %2!=0 ? 'old' : null}" 
                         rowIndexVar="cont" styleClass="background_datatable"
                         emptyMessage="Não Há Parlamentares Cadastrados" scrollRows="50"  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400" sortBy="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userNomeusuario}" 
                         selection="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.membroSelecionado}" rowKey="#{parlamentar.membrosCodigo}"
                         paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorTemplate="{Exporters}"
                         reflow="true" class="margin-top background_datatable">

                <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
                    <nav class="export-icons-nav">
                        <h:commandLink styleClass="export-icons-commandLink">
                            <p:graphicImage library="img" title="xls" name="exp_xls.png" styleClass="export-icons-img"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dtParlamentares" fileName="parlamentares" pageOnly="true"/>
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink styleClass="export-icons-commandLink">
                            <p:graphicImage library="img" title="pdf" name="exp_pdf.png" styleClass="export-icons-img"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="dtParlamentares" fileName="parlamentares" pageOnly="false"/>
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink styleClass="export-icons-commandLink">
                            <p:graphicImage library="img" title="csv" name="exp_csv.png" styleClass="export-icons-img"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="dtParlamentares" fileName="parlamentares"  />
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink styleClass="export-icons-commandLink">
                            <p:graphicImage library="img" title="xml" name="exp_xml.png" styleClass="export-icons-img"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="dtParlamentares" fileName="parlamentares"  />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </nav>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userNomeusuario}" >
                    <p:commandLink action="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.carregarDialogCuriculo()}" value="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userNomeusuario}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{parlamentar}" target="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.membroSelecionado}"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Apelido" sortBy="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userApelido}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userApelido}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Email" sortBy="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userEmail}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{parlamentar.membrosUserCodigo.userEmail}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </p:panel>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog id="dlgCurriculo" header="Currículo Parlamentar" widgetVar="widCurriculo"  appendTo="@(BODY)" resizable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" dynamic="true"
              visible="#{cidadaoParlamentaresBean.abrirCurriculo}" class="dialog-width"  >
        <h:form id="formDialog">

            <ui:include src="/telas/cidadao/CurriculoParlamentar.xhtml"/>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</ui:define>
```